# Как в std::chrono получить time_point начала текущих суток (с максимально возможной точностью)?

Tags: c++, время, c++17, std-chrono

Мне в своём проекте понадобилось получить std::chrono::time_point со временем 00:00:00 текущих суток с макимально возмой точность. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Не, ну всётаки, с точностью до милисекунды или наносекунды? Или имеется ввиду до секунды?

Comment: @nick_n_a погрешность должна быть не больше микросекунды. Работа с GPS.

Comment: @nick_n_a спрашивали то вы зачем? У вас есть какое-то решение?

Comment: Посмотрите тут асоциация http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848984/c-c-time-t-in-microseconds

Comment: @nick_n_a только что получилось решить проблему. Спасибо вам за помощь.

Comment: можете пояснить, что значит время 00:00:00 текущих суток? желательно на приере, вот сейчас на часах 10:46:35 GMT+3, какое время надо получить?

Comment: @goldstar_labs 'Wed Sep 19 00:00:00 2018' - это вывод в стандартный поток той точки, которую я получил через функцию, которую опубликовал в ответе ниже.

Comment: Стало понятнее, но не до конца, допустим сейчас 02:00:00 GMT+3 Sep 19, или 23:00:00 Sep 18 GMT+0, какой ответ будет правильным, 18е число или 19е? Иными словами нужна ли коррекция часовых поясов?

Comment: @goldstar_labs обратите внимание что в вопросе я хочу получить std::chrono::time_point а не время.

Comment: я пытаюсь понять что вам надо) время в ОС это абстрактная штука, а хроно делает всё только сложнее и непонятнее) Если вам надо точка времени начала суток, то просто берете дату и преобразовывайте её хоть в наносекунды, хоть в фемтосекунды (максимальное разрешение у хроно аттосекунды 10^-18), high_resolution_clock на разных ОС может быть по-разному объявлен внутри реализации и может давать разную точность (от мс до нс), если вам надо на ГПС слать микросекунды, то я не вижу тут причины городить огород с хроно

Comment: @goldstar_labs ну вот это просто мне и нужно было сделать. Я не знал как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему самому. В конечном итоге получилась такая функция:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> GetStartTimeOfToday (){
    using high_resolution_clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    std::time_t t_now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(high_resolution_clock::now());  // Получаем текущее время в виде std::time_t
    std::tm tmp = *localtime(&t_now); // Конвертируем в std::tm.
    tmp.tm_hour = 0; // Обнуляем все поля времени.
    tmp.tm_min = 0;
    tmp.tm_sec = 0;
    std::time_t t_start_time_of_day = std::mktime(&tmp); // Делаем обратные преобразования.
    return high_resolution_clock::from_time_t(t_start_time_of_day);
}
```

Comment: Если вы все равно опускаетесь до стандартных localtime/mktime, то зачев вам вообще крестовые заморочки с chrono? Все равно внизу будет системный вызов `clock_gettime()`

Comment: @avp после этого идёт много высокоуровнего кода который работает с time_point.

Answer (score 1):

`std::chrono` еще явно не доделан для работы в таком режим, его основное назначение - типобезопасные промежутки времени и их измерение, а не вывод их пользователю. Но в c++20 планируют добавить календари, часы в UTC и подобное (можно посмотреть [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)).

Для таких задач на практике нужно использовать библиотеки, хотя бы тот же Qt.

В качестве развлечения можно делать что-то вроде подобного:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
int main(){

    namespace chrono = std::chrono;
    auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();
    {
        auto now_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now); // Только для отладки
        auto utc_now_c = *std::gmtime(&now_c);
        auto local_now_c = *std::localtime(&now_c);
        std::cout << "UTC now:       " << std::put_time(&utc_now_c, "%c %Z") << '\n';
        std::cout << "local now:     " << std::put_time(&local_now_c, "%c %Z") << '\n';
    }

    // Будет в с++20:
    using days = chrono::duration<chrono::hours::rep, std::ratio<chrono::hours::period::num * 24>>;

    // Используем преобразование с округлением для получения остатка
    auto after_midnight_duration = now - chrono::time_point_cast<days>(now);
    auto hours = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::hours>(after_midnight_duration);
    auto minutes = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::minutes>(after_midnight_duration - hours);
    auto seconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(after_midnight_duration - hours - minutes);
    std::cout << "hours: " << hours.count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "minutes: " << minutes.count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "seconds: " << seconds.count() << '\n';

    // Для перевода в localtime или в utc нужны смещения. Вариант так себе, но вроде работает:
    static const auto localtime_offset = []{
        auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto now_c =  chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
        auto now_tm = *std::localtime(&now_c);
        now_tm.tm_hour = 0;
        now_tm.tm_min = 0;
        now_tm.tm_sec = 0;
        auto midnight_c = std::mktime(&now_tm);
        auto midnight_from_c = chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(midnight_c);
        auto midnight = now - (now - chrono::time_point_cast<days>(now));
        return midnight - midnight_from_c;
    }();
    // тут я не уверен, но вроде работает
    static const auto utc_offset = []{

      auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();
      auto now_c =  chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
      auto now_tm_local = *std::gmtime(&now_c);
      auto now_tm = *std::localtime(&now_c);
      now_tm.tm_hour = now_tm_local.tm_hour;
      now_tm.tm_min  = now_tm_local.tm_min ;
      now_tm.tm_sec  = now_tm_local.tm_sec ;
      auto utc_now_c = std::mktime(&now_tm);
      auto utc_now = chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(utc_now_c);
      return (now - localtime_offset) - utc_now;
    }();

    std::cout << "============ local time: " << '\n';
    {
        auto local_now = now + localtime_offset;
        auto after_midnight_duration = local_now - chrono::time_point_cast<days>(local_now);
        auto hours = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::hours>(after_midnight_duration);
        auto minutes = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::minutes>(after_midnight_duration - hours);
        auto seconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(after_midnight_duration - hours - minutes);
        std::cout << "hours: " << hours.count() << '\n';
        std::cout << "minutes: " << minutes.count() << '\n';
        std::cout << "seconds: " << seconds.count() << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "============ utc time: " << '\n';
    {
        auto utc_now = now + utc_offset;
        auto after_midnight_duration = utc_now - chrono::time_point_cast<days>(utc_now);
        auto hours = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::hours>(after_midnight_duration);
        auto minutes = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::minutes>(after_midnight_duration - hours);
        auto seconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(after_midnight_duration - hours - minutes);
        std::cout << "hours: " << hours.count() << '\n';
        std::cout << "minutes: " << minutes.count() << '\n';
        std::cout << "seconds: " << seconds.count() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

У меня выводит

```
UTC now:       09/19/18 22:20:20 RTZ 2 (зима)
local now:     09/20/18 01:20:20 RTZ 2 (зима)
hours: 22
minutes: 20
seconds: 20
============ local time: 
hours: 1
minutes: 20
seconds: 20
============ utc time: 
hours: 22
minutes: 20
seconds: 21
```