# Какие поставщики std::chrono::time_point существуют в С++?

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь решить [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882588/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-stdchrono-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-time-point-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be) проблему уже сутки, но пока ничего путного не получилось (Пришла в голову идея откатывать системные часы в начало суток, вызывать метод `now`, а потом синхронизировать обратно =). Но это такое.). В связи с этим появился другой вопрос, а какие поставщики  `std::chrono::time_point`, кроме методов `now` и `std::chrono::duration_cast`, вообще существуют? Интересует всё, даже если это за пределами `std` (например, `boost`, библиотека `qt` или что-то ещё).

Comment: Qt QDateTime - дата и время, QTmie - интервал, время, даже есть из коробки qint64 QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch(), поскольку вам надо до наносекунд, то тут врядли поможет

Comment: А какая разница наносекунда туда, наносекунда сюда, если это время от начала суток? там секундной точности скорее всего хватит с головой

Comment: @KoVadim нет. За секунду спутники пролетают огромное расстояние. Вы промохнётесь на несколкьо километров при расчётах.

Comment: а вот это уже интереснее. Но обычная ос (типа винда) не даст точность достаточную. Тут нужно либо в железе все это делать, либо брать отдельный источник синхронизации.

Comment: @KoVadim в изделиях где это нужно стоит linux. Но это не от OC зависит а от внутренних часов в процессоре, кварца и метода синхронизации.

Comment: и даже макось не поможет. Это все не системы реального времени. Планировщик задач легко может на 20-30 мс  позже запустить.

Comment: @KoVadim я как раз сейчас это дописываю. Возможно вы и правы, скоро узнаем.

Comment: эмм... дык GSP же должен предоставлять свои timestamp'ы высокой точности... брать время ОС в таком случае — ИМХО моветон...

Comment: gps поставляет. Но нужно как раз знать и локальное время, что бы определить позицию. Сигнал то распространяется не бесконечно быстро.